# Won't update the value

Tags: java, eclipse, math, clock, updating

I'm making a very basic automatic "Cookie Clicker" program and I got a problem with this row of code:

```
z = Math.ceil(15*java.lang.Math.pow(1.15, x));
```

when x gets updated in the if-statement this row of code doesn't seem to understand that and z keep on using x's initialized value (which is 0) and stays as 15 (15*1.15^0).

Do anyone know what to do?

```
public class Tryout {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double x = 0;               //Number of Cookie Clickers
    double z;                   // Cost of the Cookie Clickers
    double cookies = 0;         //Amount of Cookies
    double count = 0;           //Additional amount of cookies per second from the Cookie Clickers
    final double constant = 0.1; //Amount of CPS (cookies per second) you get from 1 Cookie Clicker
    z = Math.ceil(15*java.lang.Math.pow(1.15, x)); //with 0 CC the cost is 15, with 1 CC the cost is 18, with 2 CC...
    while (1>0) {               // the game loop, (infinity loop)
        if(cookies >= z) {  //If you got enough cookies you autobuy a new CC and the number of CC's increase as well as the cost of a CC
            System.out.println("cookies" + cookies); //Amount of cookies before you buy
            System.out.println("You bought a new Cookie Clicker; +0.1 cookie each second!");
            System.out.println(cookies + " - " + z + " = " + (cookies - z));
            cookies = cookies - z;
            x++;
        }


        try {  //delayer (Uptades 1 time per second)
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

        count = x*constant;
        cookies = cookies + 1 + count;
        Math.round(cookies);
        System.out.println("cookies; " + cookies);          // Your current amount of cookies
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: `z = Math.ceil(15*java.lang.Math.pow(1.15, x));` causes `z` to be assigned **at that point**.  It doesn't tell the program to recompute `z` every time `x` changes.  You have to do that yourself.

Comment: To look at it another way: `z` is a _variable_ that contains one value, and _nothing else_; `z` does not hold a "function" or a "formula".

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i didn't realize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line of code is only executed once. Move it inside the loop to have z re-evaluated each time x changes.